# Which editor to use for coding dynamic web pages

Tags: javascript, python, html

I am new to web development and I see it is very common to print HTML syntax from some server side script which is typically written in python, php, perl etc.
Now, normally all editors have some features which can help with syntax checking of the HTML as the programmer is writing them.
However, if the HTML code is emitted from a print statement, how can HTML syntax checking be done.

For example
the server side python script generating an HTML form can be like

```
print("<td><input type="file" name="upload_file" />")
```

Here the ending tag 
`</td>` is missing. Is there an editor which can warn about this. Otherwise, how do the programmers deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't display this code using `python`. If you want to create a server, you will need to look for the development of the server side (these are the three most used):

- [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)
- [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/)
- [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/)

Also, you can check more web frameworks here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks

Answer (score 1):

For any non-trivial work it's best not to embed HTML (or any other language) in your Python code.  Use a templating engine such as [jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) or one of the [others available](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebComponents).  Most Python web frameworks support integration with at least one templating engine.

Separating your code and markup by using a templating engine makes your code easier to maintain.  In particular, files for templating engine code are essentially HTML with some additional markup to allow for variable substitution, looping etc and so your editor's HTML syntax highlighting will work on them.

Answer (score 1):

use sublime, its light weight and have lots of features.